# How to find the WordPress Nextgen galleries which are not used in WordPress posts?

Tags: plugins, wp-query, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I am using **WordPress** with [**Nextgen Gallery**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) by Alex Rabe for quite sometime. Once upon a time I had a good amount galleries in my website which were used in many posts through nextgen gallery shortcode. But for quality enhancement I have deleted many posts but the galleries related to those posts remain there in file system as orphan. How to find the galleries not used in post database?

### **Table added by nextgen gallery:**

#### wp_ngg_gallery

```
Column          Type            Null    Default     Comments
gid             bigint(20)      No       
name            varchar(255)    No       
slug            varchar(255)    No       
path            mediumtext      Yes     NULL     
title           mediumtext      Yes     NULL     
galdesc         mediumtext      Yes     NULL     
pageid          bigint(20)      Yes     0    
previewpic      bigint(20)      Yes     0    
author          bigint(20)
```

---

#### wp_posts (Wordpress default table)

```
Column          Type        Null    Default         Comments
ID              bigint(20)  No           
post_author     bigint(20)  No      0    
post_date       datetime    No      0000-00-00 00:00:00      
post_date_gmt   datetime    No      0000-00-00 00:00:00      
post_content    longtext    No
```

gid is the gallery id. for an example if the gid is 8 i use the nextgen gallery shortcode **[nggallery id=8]** in the post and it is saved in the post_content field of wp_posts table. i want to know the gid's which are not present in any post_content of whole wp_posts table.

Answer (score 1):

Goto `wp_postmeta(TABLE)->  meta_key(COLUMN)->gallery_id(value)` has some value in `meta_value(COLUMN)` against your `post_id(COLUMN in this table)`

Answer (score 0):

If your galleries are `attachment` post types(?), then you could simply modify my "[Internal Link Checker Plugin](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Internal-Link-Check/blob/master/internal-links.php)" to search only for galleries.

You need to change:

```
WHERE post_content
LIKE '%{$post->post_title}%' OR '%{$post->post_name}%' 
ORDER BY post_date
```

to:

```
WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
```

This way you list the attached post types 'attachment' for the currently displayed post.

The shortcode has **nothing to do** with how the Media is stored in your database. It just cares about the *display* of the gallery.

---

**Edit:**

The following lines *should* give you all posts that have `nggallery` in the post content.

```
WHERE post_content
LIKE '%nggallery%' 
ORDER BY post_date
```

After finding and removing all those posts you can savely delete that table (I wouldn't do it before).

Comment: As I have said I created the albums manually in nextgen gallery then used shortcodes [nggallery id=x] where x is gallery id in posts. Now some posts are deleted but not those galleries. I want to find these orphan nextgen galleries.

Comment: The shortcode says nothing about the post type. They have to be saved somehow in your DB. _As I have said:_ Use the link checker and rebuild it to search and find your DB entries.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I think there are some misunderstandings. No my galleries are not attachment post types. The galleries are created using nextgen gallery plugin and not attached. I have installed Internal Link checker plugin. But you didn't said what to modify. I have checked my DB and found out the short codes are saved as [nggallery id=x] format along with other contents in wp_post table. I want to find those entries in one place.

Comment: Mate, **attachments** - like images - **are [post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Attachment)** of "type" attachment. You can simply remove the shortcodes from your post, but that doesn't solve the main problem: The **attachments in your database**. Got me now? So, if you uploaded the images for your galleries with the media uploader, then you have it right inside your database as "posts". See update.

Comment: i got it, **attachments**. But after the modifications i can see the list of all images i have uploaded by wordpress default upload option not by nextgen gallery in the post edit page. I want to print a list of nextgen galleries which are not used in any posts :(

Comment: i believe nextgen gallery images and wordpress images use different database tables to store data. nextgen gallery images are stored in wp_ngg_pictures and galleries are in wp_ngg_gallery database tables.

Comment: @coolsaint If you're right and they got a separate table, then here's a small (but important) addition: They are stored in `$wpdb->ngg_gallery`. In this case, simply exachange `$wpdb->wp_posts` with the other table name. Then only those from this table should appear (as long as they got a post type column in the table). Anyway: Update your Q with the needed details about the DB table.

Comment: Question is updated.

Comment: @coolsaint Well done. Point me at it in the next days again. I'm off for today.

Comment: are you there? will you please find out a solution?

Comment: @coolsaint - See update. It's a quick one. Hope it works.

Comment: I don't want to find posts which contains nextgen galleries, I want to find those galleries which are not used in any posts but exist in wp_ng_gallery table.

Comment: Short, because I don't want to play around here anymore: You need to: `a) get all post IDs you got in wp_posts, b) get all IDs from page_id in wp_ngg_gallery & c) match them against each other -> drop every ID that is in wp_posts result.